# Two listviews in a scrollview, ignores wrap_content for some reason

Tags: java, android, listview

I've got a scenario where I have two listviews, one above the other, I'm trying to make it so that it scrolls the top list till it gets to the bottom of that list, then goes on to the second list.

Heres the XML I have, as you can see they're both set to wrap content. It does scroll, but only shows 1 option from each listview instead of everything.

> ```
> <ScrollView
>     android:id="@+id/scrllArea"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/bottombar" >
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/topbar"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 android:text="{0} Issues"
>                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
>
>             <ListView
>                 android:id="@+id/lvIssues"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
>             </ListView>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/topbar2"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/tvTitle2"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 android:text="{0} Issues"
>                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
>
>             <ListView
>                 android:id="@+id/lvNewIssues"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>                 android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
>             </ListView>
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </ScrollView>
> ```

Comment: Above of all listview will not scroll inside scrollview and it is recomended to use scrollview and listview separately.

Comment: You should put different type of rows inside your adapter (if it's extended from BaseAdapter) Or maybe you should use the ExpendableListView to populate two listview inside a single one and get different separators

Comment: I don't really know what do you want to achieve, but do NOT use ListView inside of a ScrollView. Even Romain Guy stated, that you shouldn't do this. So you should instead refactor IMO.

Comment: Refactoring isn't an option i'm afraid. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 4):

It is advisable that you do not put one scrolling component in another. There is, however, a work around if you need the `ListView`s in this layout.  They will not scroll.  They will be expanded to full height such that all the items are visible.

Create a new class inside a new package called UI (or any other name of your choice) and paste the following:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ExpandedListView extends ListView 
{
    private android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;
    private int oldCount = 0;

    public ExpandedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (getCount() != oldCount) 
        {
            int height = getChildAt(0).getHeight() + 1 ;
            oldCount = getCount();
            params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getCount() * height;
            setLayoutParams(params);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Now define your `ListViews` as follows:

```
        <com.example.UI.ExpandedListView <!--or whatever your package path name is -->
            android:id="@+id/lvIssues"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
        </ListView>


        <com.example.UI.ExpandedListView
            android:id="@+id/lvNewIssues"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
        </ListView>
```

Note that the height attribute is set to fill_parent.  It will not visually fill it's parent component due to the limitation we enforced in the `onDraw()` method of the `ExpandedListView`.

I repeat again, however;  if you can re-factor to some other layouts, please do so because the layout you provided is not advisable.

Good luck.